# C# Converting Problems with String Array to Int Array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I`m working with C# and I have a problem at converting a string array to a int array. 
First I created a string number with the Console

```
Console.WriteLine("Geben Sie die Nummer ein:");
string wert = Console.ReadLine();
```

Then I converted the string to a array

```
char[] wertarray = wert.ToCharArray();
wertarray1 = new string(wertarray);*
```

And now comes the problem. I want to convert the string array to a int array, but e.g. for string wertarray1[0]=1, the int array has the value 49.

```
int wertarray2 = Convert.ToInt16(wertarray1[0]);
```

Normal the Int value should be 1, but I don`t know where the problem is.

I tried the solutions for "convert a string array to a int array" from this forum, but i still had the problem that the int value get a strange number.

I´m looking forward for help.
Thanks :-).

Comment: After getting the input from the Console.ReadLine test and convert to an integer using Int32.TryParse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers provided already explain your problem and provide solution too.

In general, you can convert the `char` to `string` and `parse` them to integer (not the best performance though).

If you have all numeric string

```
var numStr = "136";
var numbers = numStr.Select(n => int.Parse(n.ToString())).ToList(); // {1, 3, 6}
```

If your string contains non numbers too

```
var mixStr = "1.k78Tj_n";
int temp;
var numbers2 = new List<int>();
mixStr.ToList().ForEach(n =>
{
    if (int.TryParse(n.ToString(), out temp))
        numbers2.Add(temp);
}); //{ 1, 7, 8 }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Convert.ToInt16(Char)` takes the *numeric value* of the char (i.e. its Unicode code-point value) and returns that number. While you might think `Convert.ToInt16('1')` should return `1`, consider what would happen if you tried `Convert.ToInt16('@')` for example.

Use `Int16.Parse` (or `TryParse`) to actually parse a string to numbers. As you're working with individual characters to represent 0-9 you might as well do it using simple arithmetic without the need to call any `Parse` function:

```
String line = Console.ReadLine();
List<Int16> numbers = new List<Int16>( line.Length );
foreach(Char c in line) {
    Int16 charValue = (Int16)c;
    if( charValue < 48 || charValue > 57 ) throw new Exception("char is not a digit");
    Int16 value = charValue - 48;
    numbers.Add( value );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the [Unicode code point value](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/number-one-ascii-code-49.html) of the characters in your input stream -- 49 is the unicode value for the character `1`.

If you want to convert a unicode character that is a digit to the numeric value of that digit, you can use [`System.Globalization.CharUnicodeInfo.GetDecimalDigitValue(char c)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw9t1kbk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
    var wertarray2 = wert.Select(c => (short)CharUnicodeInfo.GetDecimalDigitValue(c)).ToArray();
```

This handles all digits (including superscripted numbers) not just the standard ASCII digits.